# Autodesk Forge _ Using Postman

Tags: postman, autodesk-forge

After Coding in Postman how to use in Visual studio for creating Forge App? i am unable to understand
Any specific logic please help with respect to arrange the folder structure in visual code for forge

Regards
Prakash Pisipati

Answer (score 0):

Forge itself doesn't require any specific folder structure or project setup. That will typically depend on the programming language you want to use, and the project type.

For example, if you're building a server application using Node.js, consider using Express.js, and following its [Getting Started](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html). And for an ASP.NET app, try this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Or, let's say you're building a .NET Core console app. In that case, try following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code.